# ValueEventListener for reading value is never getting called in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read a value from a reference in my database. It used to work but one day it just stopped working for no reason. ValueEventListener is set successfully but my problem is, it's never getting called.

- The same problem applies to all nodes in database.
- My database rules are public.
- I am connected to the internet.
- I use version 10.2.1 on Gradle. (gradle can't find file of version 10.2.4?)
- I'm using a physical device with api 23 for testing.

My code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("key");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        int value = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {}
});
```

I also noticed a message written to log every 5-10 sec

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

And also this one, not sure if there's a link

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000015/n/arm64-v8a
```

App-level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Do you have any idea why this stopped working?

Comment: Can you post the app level gradle?

Comment: Have you figured out the solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue and I can't figure out the root cause. The listener fires in one activity, but it doesn't fire anymore in the next activity.

Comment: Before I had the issue it worked then a few months after it started working again even though I had changed nothing... I don't know.

Comment: I figured out the cause. I added a database.gooffline and online commands, and it seems that the database wasn't going back online when the app switches from one activity to another. If the listener isn't firing, it could be the internet connection is off because of this offline database.